# pam.conf is empty empty

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, plesk

I have a ubuntu VPS and Plesk installed from webfusion

and i have upgraded PAM from Terminal While i'm connected to server through SSH on putty.

and now after doing that I lost access to my server using ssh,
in every time i'm trying to connect to SSH after typing the root password i'm getting wrong password.

and i tried to do small researches and i found that the reason that pam.conf is empty
Parallels has the solution here:
http://kb.parallels.com/en/1532
but this solution to fix plesk functions and can be applied only using terminal which i don't has access to it at the moment.

the only access i have is to file manager in plesk CP which i can access any file in the server,

i tried to check /etc/pam.conf and found the following contents:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# /etc/pam.conf                                  #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#
# NOTE
# ----
#
# NOTE: Most program use a file under the /etc/pam.d/ directory to setup their
# PAM service modules. This file is used only if that directory does not exist.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Format:
# serv. module     ctrl       module [path] ...[args..]          #
# name  type       flag                              #
```

and there is no "/etc/pam.d/" folder exist
how can i get access to ssh to fix plesk issues and other problems on server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall libpam-runtime to get the original pam.conf back.